# why IBtoolid increses automatically with multiple slots. even i'm having 16 GB RAM

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, libtool-xcode

[image]

screenshot shows multiple Ibtoolid slots with almost contains about total 35 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be its because xcode builds project everytime